# 2D Array Lookup-Method to return interpolated value for unknown coordinates

Tags: c#, arrays, interpolation, lookup, moving-average

I have a complete 2D array of 11 rows and 101 Columns for a car engine simulation in C#.

- Rows represent Engine RPM Values (0,1000,2000,...,8000,9000,10000)
- Columns represent throttle position in percent (0,1,2,...,98,99,100)
- The information within represents a value (e.g. Air Flow) at the given RPM and throttle position

The problem is, that i also need to know the Air Flow value between e.g. 2000 and 3000 as interpolated value.

So my use case is to have a method that returns an interpolated value in case of missing rows (RPM) in almost real-time (<10ms).

Any chance this is possible? Or do i really have to create and lookup a new array with 1000000 values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Depends. Do you know what the general relationship between the values is? Can you write down a function that will interpolate between the two values to the accuracy you expect? I assume a simple linear interpolation will not suffice :) In any case, this doesn't really have anything to do with C# in particular - you can experiment with this much more easily in Excel, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The values have been measured in real-world and may or may not have a specific relation. The values can also represent torque in another use case, whose rpm/throttle relationship is never the same between different cars. Should i try to find the nearest neighbor and somehow try to interpolate between them?

Comment: There's little point in trying to interpolate between two data points if you don't have a reasonable approximation of the relation between the two points. From what I've seen of torque and air flow graphs, though, polynomials should work reasonably well if you have enough data points. But really, this question is off-topic on StackOverflow - it's not a programming problem, it's a "give me an interpolation function for X" kind of problem. I'm not sure where's a good place to ask, though.

Comment: A simple Google search also gives this paper: https://www.win.tue.nl/casa/meetings/special/ecmi08/combustion-engines.pdf which explores your problem in quite a bit of detail :)

Comment: The gaps between the known values are very small - a simple linear interpolation between the value of array[2000,77] (=133Nm) and array[3000,77] (=145Nm)  for rpm=2576 and throttle=77 would absolutely be fine when looking up. Anyway - i thought there may be a known implementation for this problem. Thanks four your input, i will read into it.

Comment: Linear interpolation is very easy to do, so if that's good enough for you, go ahead. You'll find plenty of sample code with Google, or you can just work from first principles (in your example, `(((145 - 133) / 1000) * 576) + 133 == 139.9`). The only tricky part is avoiding precision loss due to finite data types - you'll want to be smart about the kinds of operations you do. That said, for values (and equations) like this, a simple `float` will work well even with the naïve solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would use thin-plate spline interpolation.  There is a C++ implementation [here](https://launchpad.net/templatedtps), and there is a C# / .NET wrapper for it [here](https://github.com/davidqkelly/ThinPlateSpline_DotNet).